# VS2012 C++ Overloaded member function not found / Declaration Incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

this is my first real foray into c++ so bear with me. This is also for an assignment, basically I was provided a bunch of crap .h and some test files, but no implementation file. We are expected to create the implementation file, but with so many functions missing it naturally won't compile so I cannot start coding using an iterative method. So, I am trying to create dummy implementations so that I can build each part one function at a time. I am having trouble creating a matching "dummy" implementation for this particular function in the header file. I'm sure this is `c++ 101` for hardcore programmers, but it's not so straightforward for someone learning c++ for the first time. I get it... my implementation does not match the prototype definition. How do I get the implementation to match the function prototype in the header file? Please, use small words, since I'm an amateur. :-)

```
// sequence.h
class sequence
{
public:
    size_type size( ) const;
```

The implementation file with "dummy" functions.

```
// sequence.cpp
const sequence::size_type sequence::size()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Errors:

```
Error   1   error C2511: 'const main_savitch_3::sequence::size_type main_savitch_3::sequence::size(void)' : overloaded member function not found in 'main_savitch_3::sequence'  hw1\sequence1.cpp   24  1   hw1

2   IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "main_savitch_3::sequence::size_type main_savitch_3::sequence::size() const" (declared at line 93 of "hw1\sequence1.cpp  23  38  hw1
```

Comment: How did your const keyword end up in front of your method instead of behind it? That's a different meaning and therefor a different method.

Comment: It ended up there because I don't know what I'm doing yet. :-P I see from the answers that `const` goes at the end of my function defs. I tried to be explicit about my noob-ness. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your signature has a `const` member function returning a non-const value (which makes perfect sense). So your definition needs to match that:

```
sequence::size_type sequence::size() const
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution. Swept a few more dummy functions in there and it now compiles and executes as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` at the end of the function declaration means that the function is not supposed to "modify anything" inside the class it is in, not that the return type is constant.

You should rather write

```
size_type sequence::size() const
{
    return 0;
}
```

And, since I see no code for that, you should only put the "*sequence*" qualifier in

```
sequence::size_type
```

if that type is defined (or typedefined) inside the `sequence` class.

Comment: The `size_type` comes from the sequence class (maybe not so clear from my code examples), but it won't work if it's not called as `sequence::size_type`. You were correct about `const` though. Thank you.